# Bad memory access while calling function

Tags: c, function, pointers, memory, runtime-error

Actually i developing using unit test.
But i break down my code in other form to ask for the error that i faced.

I have these declaration in my `header` file

```
typedef struct
{
    void *topOfStack;

}Stack;



typedef enum {NUMBER,OPERATOR,IDENTIFIER}Token;

int operatorEvaluate(Stack *numberStack , Stack *operatorStack);
void * pop(Stack *stack);
```

The following is the respective `source` file

```
#include "try.h"

void *pop(Stack *numberStack)
{
    Token *newToken = NUMBER;

    return newToken;

}


int operatorEvaluate(Stack *numberStack , Stack *operatorStack)
{
    Token *first = (Token*)pop (numberStack);
    if(numberStack != operatorStack)
    {
        if(*first == NUMBER)
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the source file that i call the functions which is `main`

```
#include "try.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    Stack numberStack;
    Stack operatorStack;
    int num;
    num = operatorEvaluate(&numberStack , &operatorStack);
    printf("This is the returned value:  %d",num);
    return 0;
}
```

When i tried to compile, the unit test tell me that bad memory access. 
So i try to use eclipse to compile these, and windows tells that the `.exe` had stop working.
Hope someone can help me, i stuck for a long time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable compiler warnings.

In particular, this makes zero sense:

```
Token *newToken = NUMBER;
```

That's a *pointer*, and you're assigning a *value*.

I cannot propose a fix, as I have no idea what you're doing.

Comment: Sorry for make you confusing, because i trying to make this shorter. I get what you mean, thinking some other way to overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

That `pop()` function isn't touching the stack, and is returning an enum converted to a pointer. If you try to access anything through that pointer, it's going to provoke undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Your `pop` function is wrong in a few ways. You probably want it to actually pop your stack, rather than return a constant (which it isn't doing either, by the way!)...something like this:

```
void *pop(Stack *numberStack)
{
    return numberStack->topOfStack;
}
```

but if you do that it'll still crash, because you never initialize your stack **OR** fill the `topOfStack` pointer.

Comment: Ya, true. 
But, even the logic no correct, the program still run. 
Now my problem is the program stop working in the half way.